# Authorize Customer profile creation failed error

Tags: authorize.net

i was working on charge transaction with create payment profile. but not sure why i am getting "Customer profile creation failed." error.

here is my request.

```
<createTransactionRequest xmlns='AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'>
<merchantAuthentication>
    <name>***</name>
    <transactionKey>***</transactionKey>
</merchantAuthentication>
<transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>16.0</amount>
    <payment>
        <creditCard>
            <cardNumber>5424000000000015</cardNumber>
            <expirationDate>1217</expirationDate>
            <cardCode>123</cardCode>
        </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <profile>
        <createProfile>true</createProfile>
    </profile>
    <customer>
        <id>1509041488071M1S4JO7</id>
    </customer>
    <billTo>
        <firstName>first name</firstName>
        <lastName>last name</lastName>
        <address>test address</address>
        <city>test city</city>
        <state>TX</state>
        <zip>12345</zip>
        <country>USA</country>
    </billTo>
</transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>
```

here is the response i am receiving.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><createTransactionResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
<messages>
    <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
    <message>
        <code>I00001</code>
        <text>Successful.</text>
    </message>
</messages>
<transactionResponse>
    <responseCode>4</responseCode>
    <authCode />
    <avsResultCode>P</avsResultCode>
    <cvvResultCode />
    <cavvResultCode />
    <transId>60032849402</transId>
    <refTransID />
    <transHash>50548437B6AA41F3C509C37269336E3E</transHash>
    <testRequest>0</testRequest>
    <accountNumber>XXXX0015</accountNumber>
    <accountType>MasterCard</accountType>
    <messages>
        <message>
            <code>252</code>
            <description>Your order has been received. Thank you for your business!</description>
        </message>
    </messages>
    <transHashSha2 />
</transactionResponse>
<profileResponse>
    <messages>
        <resultCode>Error</resultCode>
        <message>
            <code>E00101</code>
            <text>Customer profile creation failed.</text>
        </message>
    </messages>
</profileResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

but not sure why i am getting "Customer profile creation failed." error.

transaction is creating successfully.

Comment: Give us the entire error message or the entire response. You're also going to have to change your transaction key now that it is posted here.

Comment: never mind transaction key was sandbox text account.

Comment: i have update the question and added the response.

Comment: I didn't try this myself but the XML looks to be correct

Comment: where could i get help with this issue?

Comment: i have notices one more thing. response code is 252 instead of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response reason code 252 indicates that the transaction has been held for review because of the settings you have set in the Merchant Interface. Check your fraud screening settings in the Merchant Interface to see what it's set up to hold. Either send different test data to get around your screening filters you have set up, or change the filter settings.

Comment: yes you are right, i was getting the error because of maximum transaction allowed in one hour for same ip.

Comment: i just want to ask you one thing, did you see any case where transaction response is returning more than one messages?

Comment: For the "messages" element there will always be only 1 in whatever parent element it appears in. However, most of the places where you might see "messages", you'll have "message" as a sub-element. I can't think of a case where you would have more than one "message", but it's allowed in [the schema](https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd). For best compatibility, you'd always want to iterate through and look for multiples, but in practice, I can't think of a case where that would happen.

Comment: Also, just want to put a plug in for our [Response Code Lookup tool](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=252). If you again get a code you don't really understand, plug it in there, and for many of the codes, you'll have actual practical advice.